# Give numpy array A with is MxN and B which is DxN find the euclidean distance s.t. ijth element of AB=L2(A[i,:]-B[:,j])

Tags: python, numpy

Give numpy array A with is MxN and B which is DxN calculate the euclidean distance s.t. ijth element of AB=L2(A[i,:]-B[:,j]) without a for loop.

I thought you could do something liek

```
np.sum((x[,:] - y[,:])**2)
```

But this gives a syntax error on the y[,:]. I always thought that array[:,] would return all the rows and array[,:] would return all the columns separately.

So for example

```
x = [[0, 0], [1, 1], [1, 1]]
y = [[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [1, 0, 1]]
```

The euclidean distance of the 2 should be

```
A=[[5,4,5], [5, 4, 5]]
```

Because A[0,0] = np.sum(([0, 1, 1] - [1, 2, 1])**2)

Comment: Can you share that array? Perhaps you mean ```y[:]```

Comment: Do you really mean `A[i,:]-B[:,j]`?  According to the shapes that you gave, `A[i,:]` has length N, but `B[:,j]` has length D.

Comment: I've added an example. I don't know about the variables i and j are they for loop variables? I'm trying to avoid that.

Comment: Indexing has to follow python tuple syntax.  x[:,i]` is ok, even `x[j,]`, but not a leading comma `x[,:]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
import numpy as np
M, D, N = 100, 50, 5
A = np.random.random((M, N))
B = np.random.random((D, N))

# A.K.A AB
euclidean = np.sqrt(np.sum((A[:, None, :] - B[None, :, :]) ** 2, axis=2))
```

Comment: Perfect do you have any resources to help me learn this? I've seen this operation to add a new axis, but I'm not sure how it works. For example why is the new axis added in the 1st dim for A and 0 dim for Matrix B? How does that automatically transpose and subtract?

Comment: The inner difference produces a (M,D,N) array